# How to get mysqli results from database where the WHERE clause searches for records that have part of it, not necessarily whole of it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, where-clause

In order to understand my question let me begin with let me point how my **user_records** table looks like (Below)

```
=====================================
ID  FirstName LastName   Mtr
-------------------------------------
2   Tom       Bradley    972379-nai
3   Floyd     John       438909-jersey
4   Craig     Tommy      984389-new
5   Nelson    Harvey     783902-tow
6   Dean      Wayne      984389-jdd
7   Craig     Tommy      984389-ird
8   Mark      John       438909-carli
=======================================
```

You will realise that under **Mtr** column we have values that have an integer part as well as an alphabetical part.

The challenge is to return results from a query which the WHERE clause is column `Mtr` but only the integer part.

This is what I mean:

```
$reference = 984389;//This will be passed to the WHERE clause
/*
what is expected is that the query returns records whose Mtr part contains $reference
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_records WHERE Mtr='$reference'; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

The expected result is that the query returns records *4*, *6* and *7*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_records WHERE Mtr LIKE '%$reference%';

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

Comment: Very correct, thank you